# MapInfo to PostGIS - QGIS styles

Tags: qgis, postgis, style, mapinfo

i just discovered the possibilites and advantages of holding my data in a PostGIS database. As we work with a mix of MapInfo, QGIS (Lizmap and QField) I'm looking for a convenient way to save my data within PostGIS and access it from different GI-programms. With the EasyLoader Tool from MI i can upload my data into the DB - the style of each object is saved in a newly created column "MI-Style" (entries are looking then like:  `Pen (17,25,9445631)` . Does anyone have the matching .qml files at hand, so that QGIS can display the data the same way as in MapInfo?

Usually when opening .TAB files with QGIS the original style is shown - so somewhere there must be some kind style library in QGIS I assume.

Comment: I don't think there is a style library in terms of .qmls, QGIS seems to convert the styles in the .tab to an Embedded Style renderer. This can be converted to a Categorised renderer more suited to .qml (see [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/419432/display-embedded-symbols-in-the-layout-legend-in-qgis)) BUT the style is applied feature by feature and not very useful. Programmatic options, I guess you have looked at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132469/convert-mapinfo-styles-toward-qgis-styles)? although the scripts iare very old now and use Python 2

Comment: thanks for pointing me to the converting-to-Categorised method - this is awesome (and would have saved me a lot of effort some time ago, when i scripted the whole thing to get the color coding/linewidth etc out of this very special data format..
I guess i need to do more scripting so the MI-Style column is filled from QGIS depending on what data is filled in via QGIS.. Never would have thought bringing MI and other GIS software to "talk to each other" would be so hard :(

Comment: From what I understand one of the issues is that MapInfo stores its style quite differently, row by row rather than stored in a more hierarchical manner, so conversion is less straightforward - and there's very little financial support to convert between MI and QGIS styles these days (unlike the Arc/QGIS style conversion suite by North Road) Here in Australia it seems like the only MapInfo customers left are local governments stuck with legacy software.